# Load balancing OR Failover servers for .net application

Tags: c#, load-balancing, failovercluster

Scenario
I have service written in c#.net.

Now on my production environment I want this service to be on 2 different servers for Loadbalancing or failover of one of the server.

So for instance if one server dies the service keeps running on the other server and users are not affected OR if there is a heavy load on the site users get redirected to different servers.

For users getting on redirected on different servers is not a problem we have the software which can check whether the service is running or not. How to do session management in this case?

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you could always spin your own session management service but I don't think that is what you are looking for.

I have experience using [NCache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/) for session management and it works well enough.

Microsoft also has [Velocity](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=B24C3708-EEFF-4055-A867-19B5851E7CD2&displaylang=en) but I'm not sure it's complete yet.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question, but still searchable by Google. Since Windows 2012 there is feature called Clustered Shared Tasks. Probably not mature yet as it is manageble only via PowerShell, but maybe good start. Check this [MSDN post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/clustering/archive/2012/05/31/10312527.aspx). I'm eager to try it myself.